# Sitemap.xml change home

Tags: magento-1, cms-pages, sitemaps

On our Magento store the sitemap which Magento automatically generates from the admin panel at **Catalog > Google Sitemap** adds the *home* url to our homepage like:

```
<url>
    <loc>http://our-domain.com/home</loc>
    <lastmod>2014-11-17</lastmod>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>0.2</priority>
</url>
```

Is there a way to change it to

```
<url>
    <loc>http://our-domain.com/</loc>
    <lastmod>2014-11-17</lastmod>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>0.2</priority>
</url>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you are getting that url because the homepage is a CMS page.
In your case it has the identifier `home`.
In order to change that url you need to rewrite the method `Mage_Sitemap_Model_Resource_Cms_Page::_prepareObject` and make it look like this:

```
protected function _prepareObject(array $data)
{
    $object = new Varien_Object();
    $object->setId($data[$this->getIdFieldName()]);
    //for home set url to ''
    if ($data['url'] == 'home') {
        $data['url'] = '';
    }
    $object->setUrl($data['url']);

    return $object;
}
```

of course this won't work if you change the homepage to an other page. But it's a quick way of doing it.
If you want the clean version you have to check what is the hompage for your current store.
For this add a new member and method like this:

```
protected $_homeId = array();
public function getHomepageId($storeId)
{
    if (!isset($this->_homeId[$storeId]))) {
        $pageId = Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Cms_Helper_Page::XML_PATH_HOME_PAGE, $storeId);
        $delimeterPosition = strrpos($pageId, '|');
        if ($delimeterPosition) {
            $pageId = substr($pageId, 0, $delimeterPosition);
        }
        $this->_homeId[$storeId] = $pageId;
    }
    return $this->_homeId[$storeId];
}
```

In this case, you need to modify the `getCollection` method in the same class. Before `$page = $this->_prepareObject($row);` add this:

```
if ($row[$this->getIdFieldName()] == $this->getHomepageId($store)) {
    $row['url'] = '';
}
```

Comment: so I will need to override `app/code/core/Mage/Sitemap/Model/Resource/Cms/Page.php` as described [here](http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/)

Comment: @CreedBratton. Yep...that's what I'm saying.

Comment: great - thanks for your help.  I have a simlar question [here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/44319/6549) would you mind looking at it?

Comment: @MariusI tried this and found that the value are logging correctly in my custom log file but when I check at mysite.com/sitemap/sitemap.xml, it is still showing mysite.com/home instead of mysite.com.
Is there any need for cache clear/compilation run or something like that?

Answer (score 3):

Magento 1.9.0.0. added two events to adjust product and category XML sitemap:

- `sitemap_categories_generating_before`
- `sitemap_products_generating_before`

In [`Mage_Sitemap_Model_Sitemap::generateXml()`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1.9.0.1/app/code/core/Mage/Sitemap/Model/Sitemap.php#L177-L183) they replaced

```
    foreach ($collection as $item) {
```

with

```
    $priority   = (string)Mage::getStoreConfig('sitemap/product/priority', $storeId);
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sitemap/catalog_product')->getCollection($storeId);
    $products = new Varien_Object();
    $products->setItems($collection);
    Mage::dispatchEvent('sitemap_products_generating_before', array(
        'collection' => $products
    ));
    foreach ($products->getItems() as $item) {
```

Same for category pages, but 20 lines below they just kept `foreach ($collection as $item)` for CMS pages. I'd would adapt this method and rewrite/modify `Mage_Sitemap_Model_Sitemap` to replace it with ...

```
    $pages = new Varien_Object();
    $pages->setItems($collection);
    Mage::dispatchEvent('sitemap_cms_pages_generating_before', array(
        'collection' => $pages,
        'store_id' => $storeId
    ));
    foreach ($pages->getItems() as $item) {
```

---

Then you can use that new event to modify your CMS pages sitemap:

Event:

```
<sitemap_cms_pages_generating_before>
    <observers>
        <rename_home>
            <class>[model]/observer</class>
            <method>renameCmsHomePageUrl</method>
        </rename_home>
    </observers>
</sitemap_cms_pages_generating_before>
```

Observer:

```
public function renameCmsHomePageUrl(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $collection = $observer->getCollection();
    foreach ($collection->getItems() as $item) {
        if ($item->getUrl() === 'home') {
            $item->setUrl('');
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the code.

Using this snippet, I have created an extension to automate this process. This will work with mult-store/site configurations too. In this extension, I have updated the CMS Sitemap link generation like the follows:

```
/**
     * Generate cms pages sitemap
     */
    $homepage = (string)Mage::getStoreConfig('web/default/cms_home_page', $storeId);
    $changefreq = (string)Mage::getStoreConfig('sitemap/page/changefreq', $storeId);
    $priority   = (string)Mage::getStoreConfig('sitemap/page/priority', $storeId);
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sitemap/cms_page')->getCollection($storeId);
    foreach ($collection as $item) {
        /* Customizing sitemap generation where url key is home */
        Mage::log($item->getUrl(), NULL, 'SeoSitemap.log');
        $url = $item->getUrl();
        if ( $item->getUrl() == $homepage) {
            $url = '';
        }
        $xml = sprintf('<url><loc>%s</loc><lastmod>%s</lastmod><changefreq>%s</changefreq><priority>%.1f</priority></url>',
            htmlspecialchars($baseUrl . $url),
            $date,
            $changefreq,
            $priority
        );
        $io->streamWrite($xml);
        /* Customization ends */
    }
    unset($collection);

    $io->streamWrite('</urlset>');
    $io->streamClose();

    $this->setSitemapTime(Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->gmtDate('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    $this->save();

    return $this;
```

You can find the entire source-code from my [repository](https://bitbucket.org/thecoderin/seositemap)