# Duplicate home page indexed

Tags: magento-1.9

Google has indexed two versions of site's homepage like below. Is there any URL rewrites requires to be added to fix this? Appreciate assistance.

www.abc.com
www.abc.com/home

Comment: Pls see http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/44311/sitemap-xml-change-home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to rewrite the model file app/code/core/Mage/Sitemap/Model/Resource/Cms/Page.php

Replace bellow function **from**

```
protected function _prepareObject(array $data)
{
    $object = new Varien_Object();
    $object->setId($data[$this->getIdFieldName()]);
    $object->setUrl($data['url']);

    return $object;
}
```

**to**

```
protected function _prepareObject(array $data)
{
    $object = new Varien_Object();
    $object->setId($data[$this->getIdFieldName()]);
    //for home set url to ''
    if ($data['url'] == 'home') {
        $data['url'] = '';
    }
    $object->setUrl($data['url']);

    return $object;
}
```

Comment: If you want this, don't actually change the file but create a custom extension to override this single method. You don't want core hacks.