# Create a custom sitemap

Tags: magento-1.9, seo, sitemaps

I need information please. For the SEO, I must generate **3 sitemap.xml**.

- One with the *categories*, *sub-categories*, *pages with filters*, *guides*, and *corporates page*
- One with *the products list*
- One with *images*.

Do you know if exists an extension or if I can configure magento for that or create these functionalities

Thanks

Comment: You might want to look into: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87/generating-a-sitemap-for-a-custom-model?rq=1

Comment: You can try SEO Suite Ultimate extension

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

**XML Sitemap Generator & Splitter**

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/xml-sitemap-generator-splitter.html